# How do I make one border of a selection be a shared border with another selection?

Tags: gimp

I'm using GIMP to label data in an image, for a machine learning application.  I simply want to divide the image into five colors, and I'm using the selection tool (Scissors Select) to outline the various regions.  My question is, if I outline one region, and paint it red, how can I use the *top* border of this previously selected region to be the *bottom* border of a new region? (Let's say I will paint this new region blue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. with the Red selection still there: `Select>Save to channel`
2. make a selection for Blue, with some overlap with Red
3. open the Channels list, right click the saved selection, and choose `Subtract from selection`. This will remove from your current Blue selection the bit that was in the Red selection.